# interpretation of independent linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, algebraic-independence

Let $Ax\leq b$ be a system of linear inequalities where $A\in R^{m\times n}$, $x\in R^n$ and $b\in R^m$.

Suppose  $A$ is a matrix with linearly independent rows.

I wonder what would be the geometric or intuitive interpretations of these independent constraints?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope

Comment: Normally, linear independence of the rows of $A$ is considered when the constraints are expressed as $Ax=b$, $x\geq 0$, rather than as $Ax \leq b$.  In the equation constraints situation, you can eliminate linearly dependent rows of $A$ without changing the feasible set.  You can't do that in the $Ax \leq b$ form.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a long comment instead of answer. I think $Ax\leq b$, with $A$ containing linearly independent rows will always be an **unbounded set**. While it's pretty straight forward to see geometrically. I am wondering if there exits a formal proof.

Comment: Update1: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233864/if-a-has-independent-rows-is-the-set-x-mid-ax-preccurlyeq-b-an-unboun