# If $A$ has independent rows, is the set $\{x \mid Ax \preccurlyeq b\}$ an unbounded set?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming

Let's say we look at the set $S = \{x\mid Ax\preccurlyeq b\}$ where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ has independent rows, $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $ b\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Can we prove that set $S$ is always unbounded? Geometrically, It seems obvious that the number of equations won't be enough to bound the set $S$. Looking for a bit more mathemtical proof!

Note: $a \preccurlyeq b$ is defined as componentwise inequality between vectors $a$ and $b$.

Details: This came to mind while answering the question: [interpretation of independent linear inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232786/interpretation-of-independent-linear-inequalities/4233031#4233031)

Comment: What order are you using for the $\le ?$.  I don't know of a standard one in $\Bbb R^m$

Comment: @RossMillikan I believe that this is the partial order generated by comparing componentwise. So, $(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \le (y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ if and only if $x_i \le y_i$ for all $i$. The inequality $Ax \le b$ is a standard way of specifying a [convex polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope).

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the clarification. Yes I meant the same thing. I have also edited the question now.

Comment: @ShivTavker You should add some of your own thoughts about this problem. Mods are now handing down suspensions for people answering questions like these.

Comment: @TheoBendit Ahh I see. Okay I will try to link one of my answers from where this came in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $S$ is always unbounded. The key observation is, if $A$ has linearly independent rows, then $AA^\top$ is invertible (see: [Moore-Penrose Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Linearly_independent_rows)). We will accordingly consider
$$A^+ = A^\top (A A^\top)^{-1}.$$
Note that $AA^+ = AA^\top(AA^\top)^{-1} = I$.

Let $\mathbf{1} = (1, 1, \ldots, 1)^\top \in \Bbb{R}^n$. We will also define $x_0 = A^+ b$ and $d = -A^+\mathbf{1}$. Then, for $\lambda \ge 0$,
$$A(x_0 + \lambda d) = AA^+(b -\lambda \mathbf{1}) = b - \lambda \mathbf{1} \preccurlyeq b,$$
so $x_0 + \lambda d \in S$. This is an unbounded ray if and only if $d \neq 0$, which follows from
$$Ad = AA^+(-\mathbf{1}) = -\mathbf{1} \neq 0.$$
Thus, $S$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

If $m>n$, then the rows of $A$ form $m$ vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence they are linearly dependent, which contradicts your hypothesis.

If $m<n$, by virtue of the incomplete basis theorem, we bring back the problem to the case $m=n$ by completing the rows of $A$ with $n-m$ vectors to obtain a square matrix $B$ such that $rank(B^T)=n$. As the new set $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\, |\,Bx \preccurlyeq b \right\}$ is a subset of $S$, if it is unbounded, so is $S$.

We are left with the case $m=n$. We have $rank(A^T)=rank(A)=n$ hence $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Now the clever part. Consider:

$$\begin{cases}x_0&=A^{-1}b \\
v(t)&=A^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}t & \dots & t\end{array}\right)^T
\end{cases}$$

And:
$$\begin{aligned} L&=\left\{x_0-v(t) \,|\, t\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\right\}\\
\end{aligned}$$

$L$ is clearly unbounded (take $t\rightarrow +\infty$), and since

$$\begin{aligned} S\cap L&=\left\{x_0-v(t) \,|\, t\in\mathbb{R}^{+}, A\left(x_0-v(t)\right)\preccurlyeq b \right\}\\
&=\left\{x_0-v(t)\, |\, t\in\mathbb{R}^{+}, b-\left(\begin{array}{ccc}t & \dots & t\end{array}\right)^T\preccurlyeq b \right\}\\
&=L
\end{aligned}$$
we have $L\subset S$. So $S$ is unbounded as well.

Answer (score 1):

The set $A b\le b$ will be bounded if and only if the cone generated by the rows of $A$ will be the whole space. Therefore, you need at least $n+1$ rows for boundedness ( necessary, but not sufficient condition).

An equivalent condition for boundedness: the point $0$ is contained in the interior of the cone generated by  of the rows of $A$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $0$ is contained in the interior of the convex hull of the rows of $A$ (otherwise there would be a supporting hyperplane through $0$).